# How to query for missing fields and associations and return what's missing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, relational-division

I am learning more raw SQL after coming from years of Rails and other ORMs, so have quite a ways to learn how to do complex queries efficiently. What I'm wondering here is _how to find all users which are missing some fields and associations, and returning which fields/associations they are missing.

I have a rough idea of how to write this in SQL but not exact (for PostgreSQL).

I have something like this data model, a table of users, a table of "social media links", and an association mapping the link to the user, so a user can have many social media links, but there could be more than one user associated with one link (i.e. organizations):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  description TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE sociallinks (
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  type VARCHAR(255),
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE usersociallinks (
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users;
  sociallink_id INTEGER REFERENCES sociallinks,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The question is, how do you perform the query (with this pseudocode):

```
select from users
join on usersociallinks.user_id = users.id
join on sociallinks.id = usersociallinks.id
where name = null
  or description = null
  or missing linkedin? (sociallinks.type == linkedin)
  or missing facebook? (sociallinks.type == facebook)
return slug from users table
return has_name = false if name is null from users table
return has_description = false if description is null from users table
return has_linkedin = false if linkedin is null from sociallinks table
return has_facebook = false if facebook is null from sociallinks table
```

In natural language, "select the users which either don't have a name or a description, or are missing a linkedin or facebook link (sociallinks.value), and return what fields they are missing".

I can do this the naive, long and convoluted way or querying one thing at a time, but I'm wondering how to do this efficiently, in possibly just one query (or as few queries as possible).

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE name IS NULL
  OR description IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Fetch those, then do:

```
const record = await knex.raw(SQL)
const output = {}
if (!record.name) output.hasName = false
if (!record.description) output.hasDescription = false
return output
```

Then the next query is more complex, but I would do one at a time.

How do you do it somewhat efficiently and in as few queries as possible? Fetching with a limit of say 100 users per query.

Input data would be:

```
users:
id,slug,name,description
1,foo,Foo,Im a description
2,bar,,Im a description too
3,baz,,
4,hello,Hello,
5,world,,
6,food,Foo,Im a descriptiond
7,bard,,Im a description tood
8,bazd,asdf,fdsa
9,hellod,,
10,worldd,,A worldd description

sociallinks:
id,type,value
1,facebook,foo
2,facebook,bar
3,facebook,baz
4,facebook,hello
5,facebook,world
6,linkedin,foo
7,linkedin,bar
8,linkedin,baz
9,linkedin,hello
10,linkedin,world

usersociallinks:
id,user_id,sociallink_id
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,2,6
4,3,7
5,5,3
6,8,4
7,8,8
8,9,9
```

Output data would be:

```
user_id,slug,has_name,has_description,has_linkedin,has_facebook
1,foo,true,true,false,true
2,bar,false,true,true,true
3,baz,false,false,true,false
4,hello,true,false,false,false
5,world,false,false,false,true
6,food,true,true,false,false
7,bard,false,true,false,false
// 8 has everything so it is missing
9,hellod,false,false,true,false
10,worldd,false,true,false,false
```

Comment: The pseudo code doesn't help much.  For a pure SQL question, it would be much more helpful to show the input and output table data.

Comment: The solution is `(not) EXISTS(...)`

Comment: Your desired results hard code the link types in to the column names. Does that mean there are and always will be only two link types? If you need this to cope with multiple and/or growing numbers of link types, I recommend one output row per user/type combination that is missing (normalised).

Comment: @MatBailie I don't quite fully understand what that would look like, but feel free to change the output so it makes more sense. That is just what is needed in some form or another. Thanks.

Comment: @MatBailie oh sorry, there will be potentially 100 different types let's say, so not just two. The total number is unknown but not too large.

Comment: With 100 social media types you;ll will end up with the double `NOT EXISTS()` pattern. See the related questions under the `relational-division` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXISTS()` to the rescue:

---

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug
        , (u.name > '' ) AS has_name 
        , (u.description> '' ) AS has_description
        , EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usersociallinks sl JOIN sociallinks s ON s.id = usl.sociallink_i
                 WHERE sl.user_id = u.id AND s.type = 'facebook') AS has_facebook
        , EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usersociallinks sl JOIN sociallinks s ON s.id = usl.sociallink_i
                 WHERE sl.user_id = u.id AND s.type = 'linkedin') AS has_linkedin
FROM users u
ORDER BY u.id
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

> select the users which either don't have a name or a description, or are missing a linkedin or facebook link (sociallinks.value), and return what fields they are missing

I would think two `left join`s:

```
with usl as (
      select usl.*, sl.type
      from usersociallinks usl join
           sociallinks sl
           on sl.id = usl.sociallink_id
     )
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when u.name is null then 'name' end),
                 (case when u.description is null then 'description' end),
                 (case when usl_f.user_id is null then 'facebook' end),
                 (case when usl_l.user_id is null then 'linkedin' end)
                ) as missing_values
from users u left join
     usl usl_f
     on usl_f.user_id = u.id and usl_f.value = 'facebook' left join
     usl usl_l
     on usl_l.user_id = u.id and usl_l.value = 'linkedin'
where u.name is null or u.description is null or
      usl_f.user_id is null or usl_l.user_id is null
```

Comment: Oh wow this is so clever I never would have considered these possibilities, thanks! Wow, how is this even resolved, `case when u.name` comes before the variable `from users u` is defined, etc... But that's another story haha.

Comment: Do you mean `usl_f.user_id` instead of `usl_f_user_id`, etc.?

Comment: @LancePollard . . . Yes.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT u.id, u.slug, 
       MAX(name) IS NOT NULL has_name, 
       MAX(description) IS NOT NULL has_description, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.type = 'linkedin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::boolean has_linkedin, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.type = 'facebook' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::boolean has_facebook
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN usersociallinks usl ON usl.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN sociallinks s ON s.id = usl.sociallink_id AND s.type IN ('facebook', 'linkedin')
GROUP BY u.id, u.slug
ORDER BY u.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a21a5fd62d09dc2c2d38762fc1df27be).

Comment: Wow so cool, thank you! Learning a lot from this right now.